# how to handle the event at a mac os view or it's subview been focused?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I create a windows has a `NSSplitview`. It has two subview, as viewA and viewB, and they has some subviews. If the  viewA or its subview get focus, set the window's title as viewA's stringValue, and viewB as so on.

How can I do it? I try to rewrite the view's

> become/access/reignFirstResponser

for viewA/B or their subView (a `NSTableView`) but is failed.

e, I try to a again what override the becomeFirstresponse at the tablview as

```
BOOL ret = [super becomeFirstResponder];
[NSApp sendAction:@selector(requestString:) to:Nil from:self.window.windowController];
return ret;
```

It works! But with coding, new subviews while appended. So I need some way with more smart and clear.

I got it! In the window delegate, I implement the windowDidUpdate as:

```
- (void)windowDidUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {
[NSApp sendAction:@selector(requestString:) to:Nil from:self.window.windowController];
```

}

The -(IBAction)requestString:(id)sender method is the viewA/B's Controller method.

Comment: Does post notification in becomeFirstResponder method not work? The notification failed or the setTitle failed?

Comment: No. I override the becomeFirstResponder method in the viewA/B or their subview that tableviews but no run. I'm try to do use windowDelegate.

Comment: e, I try to a again what override the becomeFirstresponse at the tablview as `    BOOL ret = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    [NSApp sendAction:@selector(requestString:) to:Nil from:self.window.windowController];
    return ret;
` . It works! But with coding, new subviews while appended. So I need some way with more smart and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override canBecomeKeyView in NSView class

```
-(BOOL) canBecomeKeyView
{
    return YES;
}
```